# How to capture the error message of the each activity among the multiple activities(3) in a pipeline using single stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-monitoring

I have a ADF pipeline with 3 different activities in sequence. I want to capture the error message of the activity whichever gets failed. So I have created a stored procedure by passing a parameter with which it can capture using `@activity('Activity name').Error.Message`

But using that expression I can only get the error message for the specified activity.

How can I capture the error message of *any* activity (of three activities in the pipeline)
This would be the pipeline output as the activities are in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to create three stored procedure to capture error message of correspond activity.

Answer (score -1):

```
@concat(activity('Activity1').Error?.message,'|',activity('Activity2')?.Error?.message,'|',activity('Activity3')?.Error?.message)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).